# How to search through all changes ever made in the Git repo?

Tags: git

I want to get commits in any branches, which changes (diff with the previous commit) contain specific identifier. Search in the file history is not sufficient, because the function (target identifier is it's name) was moved from file to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
git log -p --branches
```

This gives patches for all commits pointed to by a branch, directly or indirectly.